# gsub giving improper replacement

Tags: r, gsub

I am doing a simple replacement using gsub

```
 > gsub('[^0-9.]','',100000)
 [1] "105"
```

the regexp is to match any non numerical value and replace with ''. Can anyone tell me why I am getting `105`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the `options` for scientific notation as it is converting to scientific notation

```
options(scipen=999)
gsub('[^0-9.]','',100000)
#[1] "100000"
```

Without setting the options

```
sub('[^0-9.]','',100000)
#[1] "1+05"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, this is great ifo